# ios swift : How can i delay cell to appear in a tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have `uitableview` and I wanna make cells show one after one
 that's gonna after number of seconds

I have tried `sleep(2)` and `dispatchafter` inside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method but neither works

I just want that returned cell to wait number of seconds. 
Here's the code :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")! as! CustomCell

    cell.chatText.text = self.texts[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    sleep(4)
    return cell
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: do you want the delay for every cell or for all cells at once ?

Comment: every cell , just like First cell appear ----- 2 seconds ------ second cell appear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift 2.1+, this should get you an animated insertion of a cell to your tableView. I'd put the dispatch_after in your viewDidAppear or viewDidLoad of your UITableViewController or UIViewController that contains the tableView.

```
let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([YourIndexPathYouWantToInsertTo], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

And to create an NSIndexPath:

```
NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
```

Comment: an error appear tableview.endupdate() just after the delay , i'm using custom cell class and Canvas animations within uiview within each cell , does that cause the crash ?

Comment: it worked Thaaannnnnkkks after i insert an array i know it's stupid mistake from me but it's okay i'm biggener, it's been 3 hours good god, Really Thanks bro

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. Keep coding. It gets easier.

Answer (score 4):

In `cellForRow` method add this code :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")! as! CustomCell

    cell.chatText.text = self.texts[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    let delay = 0.55 + Double(indexPath.row) * 0.5; //calculate delay
    print(delay) // print for sure

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: delay, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: {
        cell.alpha = 1.0 // do animation after delay
    }, completion: nil)

    return cell
}
```

You have to set up more and more delay for each cell to see animation and display one cell after another

Hope it help you

Comment: That's another wonderful way from another wonderful person it's really easier , i'll try it , Really Thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

Try `performSelector(selector:, withObject:, afterDelay:)`. Put the method in your cell function and create another function (which is going to be the selector for `performSelector`) where you show the cells. Technically it should work (it should delay each cell return) but I can't guarantee that it will in your case. Give it a try!

Comment: Thanks! i'll try that now. but the problem now i'm just beginner but i'll do my best